# Search list JSONField postgres Django

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a JSONField which is an empty list ([]) by default. The data stored in the field is as follows:
[{"operand":"key1", "value":"value1"},{"operand":"key2", "value":"value2"} and so on....]
Now the value of the keys can be an array also like:
[{"operand":"key1", "value":["value1","value2","value3"]}]

Now I want to search this JSONField and return the result if the search query is present in the values of either "operand" or "value".

So for example is search query comes as "value", "value1", "key", "key2", the above mentioned record should be returned.

So how to implement it in Django?

Comment: If data has such strict format, it is often *not* a good idea to work with JSON, in that case an extra model is made with a `key` and `value` field, and with a `ForeignKey` to the model that now contains the `JSONField`.

Comment: It is not a strict format. But I have to search only in values and not the keys.

Comment: but how is this a non-strict format. You explain that it is a list of key/value pairs.

Comment: I mean yes the JSON is in strict format but I have not created a separate table as the requirement would be easily solved when we store data in the JSON field because in future the format can change and all. That's why I went with this approach but I'm finding it hard to search in the JSON.